# Developing maps using Tile Mill and Processing(.org)?

Tags: web-mapping, java, visualisation, processing.org

I had a small question. I actually would like to build an application which is very [similar to this](http://tillnagel.com/2011/06/tilemill-for-processing/) but as a  map and not on “Multi touch Table Top”.

The functionality I need is

1. Plot different cities of California with different radii. The radius will represent the number of times a person has visited a city.
2. When a person clicks on a city (e.g LA) it should show a polyline to other cities which are nearby, as shown in the link above.

I was wondering if anyone could help with this and give me some pointers on how to get started which would be real great.